# Finding the third point of an equilateral triangle in three dimensions.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> The coordinate of A is (4,-3,5) and the coordinate B is (6,7,8). Find the coordinate of C such that triangle ABC forms equilateral triangle

It is easy to work in two dimension Cartesian coordinates. But I have no clue how to do this in three dimensions.

Comment: The set of all solution $C$ points will form a circle in a plane orthogonal to the segment $AB$. The length of this segment is $\sqrt{113}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between the points $(4|-3|5)$ and $(6|7|8)$ is $\sqrt{(6-4)^2+(7+3)^2+(8-5)^2}$ or $\sqrt{2^2+10^2+3^2}$ or $\sqrt{4+100+9}$ or $\sqrt{113}$. Since the segment connecting the two points forms one of the sides of an equilateral triangle, the other two sides wil be of the same length. On the circle constituting the intersection of the two spheres $\begin{cases}
(x-4)^2+(y+3)^2+(z-5)^2=113\\
(x-6)^2+(y-7)^2+(z-8)^2=113\\
\end{cases}$, any point will be a candidate for the sought-after third vertex. Here is the parametric form for this circle:
$\begin{cases}
x=f(10,3,-20)\\
y=f(4,0,13)\\
z=f(13,-2,-30)\\
\end{cases}$, where $f(a,b,c)={{a\sqrt{13}+b\sqrt{339}\cos\theta+c\sqrt 3\sin\theta}\over{2\sqrt{13}}}$.
This form, I think, will be the most useful to @user87398.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, there are a lot of points $C$ that satisfy this.

For two points $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ in 3D space, the distance $d$ is given by:
$$d = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)² + (y_2 - y_1)² + (z_2 - z_1)²}$$
Now, if we let the unknown point $C = (x,y,z)$ and know that $ABC$ is equilateral, this means each side must have length:
$$AB=\sqrt{(6-4)²+(7--3)²+(8-5)²}=\sqrt{113}$$

Hence we get the two equations

$$AC = \sqrt{(4 - x)² + (-3 - y)² + (5 - z)²} = \sqrt{113}$$
$$BC = \sqrt{(6 - x)² + (7 - y)² + (8 - z)²} = \sqrt{113}$$

Squaring both sides provides us with
$$(4 - x)² + (-3 - y)² + (5 - z)² = (6 - x)² + (7 - y)² + (8 - z)²$$
which simplifies to:
$$4x+20y+26z=99$$
Picking any $x,y,z$ that satisfy this equation (and are not a false root) gives you a valid point $C$.

Comment: What you got is the plane where the circle lives. We must combine it to one of the two equations (about $AC$ or $BC$).

Comment: In any event, the equation is $4x+20y+6z=99$, which is the locus of the vertices of all isosceles triangles whose base is the segment connecting the two points.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, 4x+20y+6z=99 is of course a plane. Substitute z=(99-20y-4x)/6 into on of the equations for AC or BC and squaring both sides should give us an equation for a circle?